# Create Range from current cursor position Word 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a `.docm` document with a user form. On the user form I have a button that needs to insert something (some text, for starter) at the last known cursor position in the document. For this, I want to create a range.

How can I get the starting position for this range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `Selection` is the current position in the document.
- `Selection.Range` is the Range object of the current `Selection`.
- `Range.Start` is the start position of a `Range` object (returns or sets a Long).

If you combine those three you get the cursor position (or the start of the selection if you have text selected):

```
Selection.Range.Start
```

If you only want to enter text att the cursor position the following will do:

```
Selection.TypeText "Test"
```