# Save the cursor position in a document and return there later on

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a macro that scans my document for `Heading 1` styles, and consequently the cursor is moved to after the last match.

I'm trying to capture the location of the cursor before this scan occurs, and then return to that position after it has finished. How do I do this?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807860/create-range-from-current-cursor-position-word-2010-vba) on SO, but it's not working (No error, it just doesn't do anything.)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turn screen updates off so the user will not know that the cursor has moved

Dim currentPosition As Long
currentPosition = Selection.Range.Start

{... do stuff here ...}

Selection.Range.Start = currentPosition

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Dim currentPosition As Range
Set currentPosition = Selection.Range 'pick up current cursor position

' do stuff — cursor gets moved around

currentPosition.Select 'return cursor to original position
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I do have one very petty request, if you happen to know the answer though - Even though the selection remains as it was before, the screen moves so that the selection is at the top of the screen. Is there anyway to also save the screen position? Thanks.

Comment: Good question... I suggest you post a new question. I don't know off the top of my head; you will get more attention with a new question.

Comment: @DavidGard Scroll position: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765988/600135

Comment: Does it mean that we can't get selection of an **inactive** document?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use bookmarks:

```
Sub test()
    ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add ("xx")
    {... do stuff here ...}
    ThisDocument.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="xx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that does not seem to be working.