# Programmatically Add Hyperlink to String

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to automate Email Signature creation in VB.NET using Word Interop.

Everything works fine apart from attempting to programmatically add hyperlinks, such as (for example) an email address - it's all well and good writing the email in and expecting the other ends mail client/browser to convert it but I'd like to specify links myself (for things like social links, our privacy policy etc.)

Here are relevant segments of the code I am using:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Dim objWord As Word.Application = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = False

Dim objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Dim objSelection = objWord.Selection
Dim objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Dim objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Dim objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

Try
    If Len(strEmail) > 0 Then
        objSelection.TypeText(strEmail)
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Using the example [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/06/25/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-microsoft-office-outlook-signature/), I believe I should be using the following in place of `objSelection.TypeText(strEmail)` is...

```
If Len(strEmail) > 0 Then
    Dim objEmailRange = objSelection.Range.Start()
    objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objEmailRange, strEmail, , , strEmail)    
End If
```

...however this throws a COM Exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Signature_v2.exe
Command failed
```

Am I defining the range start correctly (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807860/create-range-from-current-cursor-position-word-2010-vba))? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperlink isn't the actual text; it's just a decoration on text that already exists.  You have to hand a range, selection, or document to the first parameter ("Anchor") of `Hyperlinks.Add()`.

Example:

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="http:\\www.microsoft.com"
```

Comment: You add a hyperlink to an existing text element, yes.  I'll see if I can find an example.

Comment: Problem solved with this code - `objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=objSelection.Range, Address:=strEmail, TextToDisplay:=strEmail)`. Thanks.